# JPA Mapping getresultlist() to entity class is not working

Tags: java, jpa, entity, hibernate-entitymanager

```
List<UserModel> ml = emf.createNamedQuery("user-model",usermodel.class).getSingleResult();
```

results in `org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0;`

If I remove the usermodel.class mapping, it is working good and get the expected result.
What mistake I am doing here and what is the efficient way of mapping resultlist to entity or pojo class?

Comment: does usermodel.class compile? should be UserModel.class

Comment: what is query - "user-model" ?    InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException is thrown when query fails to compile.   reference:  https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/dao/InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException.html )

Comment: It is UserModel.class. sry for the confusion

Comment: what is query - "user-model" ?

Comment: what is query - "user-model"?

Answer (score 0):

[InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/dao/InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException.html)

> Exception thrown on incorrect usage of the API, such as failing to "compile" a query object that needed compilation before execution. This represents a problem in our Java data access framework, not the underlying data access infrastructure.

[createNamedQuery](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/dao/InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException.html)

```
@NamedQuery(
name="findAllCustomersWithName",
query="SELECT c FROM Customer c WHERE c.name LIKE :custName")

customers = em.createNamedQuery("findAllCustomersWithName")
.setParameter("custName", "Smith")
.getResultList();
```

[getSingleResult](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/TypedQuery.html#getSingleResult--) returns single Object. So code you shared does not compile List = .

Read API documents and correct code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will correct my code